# In Python ASTs, when would the targets of an unpacked assignment be a list instead of a tuple?

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

According to the [GreenTreeSnakes documentation on Assignment statements](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nodes.html#Assign):

> An assignment. `targets` is a list of nodes, and `value` is a single node.
>
> Multiple nodes in `targets` represents assigning the same value to each.
>   Unpacking is represented by putting a `Tuple` or `List` within `targets`.

My question is, when does the unpacking put the targets in a List instead of a Tuple? The example given unpacks into a Tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In assignments, targets can both be lists and tuples:

```
a, b, c = value  # assign to a tuple of names
[a, b, c] = value  # assign to a list of names
```

The difference is cosmetic to Python; see the [*Assignment statement* reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements).

Demo:

```
>>> parseprint('[a, b, c] = value')
Module(body=[
    Assign(targets=[
        List(elts=[
            Name(id='a', ctx=Store()),
            Name(id='b', ctx=Store()),
            Name(id='c', ctx=Store()),
          ], ctx=Store()),
      ], value=Name(id='value', ctx=Load())),
  ])
```